Using SELECT ... FOR UPDATE as a way to lock a whole table
I know I can lock a whole table using LOCK TABLE, but I am just curious if I can get the same result by using the FOR UPDATE statement, assuming that all transactions that update that table select a specific row from that table using FOR UPDATE at the beginning of their transaction (or maybe having a separate table called locks with one unique column named lock_name and using SELECT lock_name FROM locks WHERE lock_name = 'foo' FOR UPDATE to acquire a lock before each transaction)?
I am asking this question because I have to save a tree data structure in a database table using either an adjacency list or a closure table. When multiple users try to add a new node or relocate a sub-tree, I have to select some rows and do some calculations and then update the table based on those calculations and this operation is not possible unless I lock the whole table.

Sounds like an "X-Y Problem" to me.  What are you actually trying to achieve?
Forcing transactions to execute "one after another" is largely taken care of by existing Transaction serialisation mechanics.

@PhillW. Not when updating a table is dependent on the current state of the table itself.

State of the table?  RDBMSs are tuple-oriented, which is what the Primary Key is for.

Maybe it's because I'm not really a PostgreSQL guy, but your post is a little confusing to me. You say there's an explicit way to lock the whole table, then pose a question on if it can be locked with a nontraditional solution, without explaining why you can't use the dedicated way to do so. Why?

@J.D. Because I just want know. It is like asking for proof of a mathematical theorem.


assuming that all transactions that update that table select a specific row from that table using FOR UPDATE at the beginning of their transaction

Of course, with this special assumption, you get the same result with either LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE or SELECT ... FOR UPDATE. Assuming by "update that table", you mean "write anything" - including INSERT, DELETE, MERGE.
The alternative you are pondering sounds a lot like advisory locks.
